# How display selected items from combobox java?

Tags: java

Here's my code that I have so far.

```
    import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.*;



import java.awt.Component; 


public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String grade = null, sub = null;
        int x = 0;
        ALevel[] array = new ALevel[3];

        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("COURSE CHECKER");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(430, 100);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 

        frame.add(panel);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Select your subject(s):");
        lbl.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        //lbl.setVisible(true); 

        panel.add(lbl);

        //define items in a String array
        String[] choices = { "MATHEMATICS", "FURTHER MATHEMATICS", "ACCOUNTING", "ECONOMICS",
                             "MANAGEMENT OF BUSINESS", "COMPUTER STUDIES", "PHYSICS", "CHEMISTRY",
                             "BIOLOGY", "DESIGN & TECHNOLOGY", "GEOGRAPHY"};


        //create combobox/dropdown with the fixed array
        final JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);

        cb.setMaximumSize(cb.getPreferredSize()); 
        cb.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        //cb.setVisible(true); 
        panel.add(cb);

        frame.setVisible(true); 

        array[x] = new ALevel(grade, sub);
        array[x].gradecheck(sub, array[x].getaGrade());
    }

        cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(Action e){
                String data = "Subject Selected: " + cb.getItemAt(cb.getSelectedIndex());
                    lbl.setText(data);
            }

        };

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Select your grades");
        lbl1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        //lbl.setVisible(true); 

        panel.add(lbl1);

        //define items in a String array
        String[] choices1 = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

        //create combobox/dropdown with the fixed array
        final JComboBox<String> cb1 = new JComboBox<String>(choices1);

        cb1.setMaximumSize(cb1.getPreferredSize()); 
        cb1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        //cb.setVisible(true); 
        panel.add(cb1);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("OK");
        btn1.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.add(btn1);

        frame.setVisible(true); 


    for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        System.out.println("\nSubject: " + array[x].getaSub() + "\nGrade:" + array[x].getaGrade());
    }
    System.out.println("\nPoint: " + array[0].getaScore());



        //
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String grade = null, sub = null;
        int x = 0;
        ALevel[] array = new ALevel[3];

        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.print("Enter subject: ");
            sub = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter grade: ");
            grade = input.nextLine();

            array[x] = new ALevel(grade, sub);
            array[x].gradecheck(sub, array[x].getaGrade());
        }

        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println("\nSubject: " + array[x].getaSub() + "\nGrade:" + array[x].getaGrade());
        }
        System.out.println("\nPoint: " + array[0].getaScore());
        System.out.println("You are eligible for: ");

        for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            if (array[x].getSubjects() == 3) {
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].getSubscoreE() >= 3 && array[x].getaScore() >= 200) {
                    array[x].SCI();
                }
                if (array[x].getSubscoreE() >= 3 && array[x].getaScore() >= 200) {
                    array[x].SOB();
                }
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].getSubscoreS() >= 2 && array[x].getaScore() >= 240) {
                    array[x].CEPA();
                }
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].isPhyscheck() == true && array[x].getSubscoreS() >= 2
                        && array[x].getaScore() >= 220) {
                    array[x].E3PA();
                }
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].isPhyscheck() == true && array[x].isChemcheck() == true
                        && array[x].getaScore() >= 240) {
                    array[x].PCEPA();
                }
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].isPhyscheck() == true && array[x].getSubscoreS() >= 2
                        && array[x].getaScore() >= 240) {
                    array[x].MEPA();
                }
            }
            if (array[x].getSubjects() == 2) {
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].getSubscoreE() >= 2 && array[x].getaScore() >= 180) {
                    array[x].SCI();
                }
                if (array[x].getSubscoreE() >= 2 && array[x].getaScore() >= 180) {
                    array[x].SOB();
                }
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].isPhyscheck() == true && array[x].getaScore() >= 180) {
                    array[x].E3PA();
                }
                if (array[x].isMathcheck() == true && array[x].isPhyscheck() == true && array[x].getaScore() >= 180) {
                    array[x].MEPA();
                }
            }
            if (array[x].getaScore() < 180) {
                System.out.print("None");
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }//
    }
}
```

the codings work well without the combobox and the data are dsiplayed in the console tab.

I want to make it easier by choosing data from combobox rather than enter input. 
So, how do i display the selected item from the combobox?

Comment: `cb.getSelectedItem()`, no? I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: It will be a lot easier for others to help you, if you edit your question and post code which compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the "selected item" from the combobox.

Then you can update your label, text area, or whatever else with the data it grabbed from your combobox.

```
JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
String myName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
updateLabel(myName);
```

Note the `cb.getSelectedItem()`. That's what's actually grabbing the data from the combobox.

And here's a good resource with some more info about using Java comboboxes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: @user3439948 No problem. If it helped you out mark it as the "accepted answer" (check mark) so other users can see it, and so people don't have to bother answering your question again when you're already done with the problem.